# iOS Get GPS Coordinates When No cellular Data

Tags: ios, gps, cllocationmanager

I need to be able to get GPS coordinates on my iOS app, even with no data.  I did not think this would be an issue, as GPS is separate from cellular signal, but I am having issues with this.  Here is what I have so far.  If Cellular Data is off, I don't get any error messages, it just fails to get coordinates and leaves those values null:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    self.locationManager.distanceFilter=kCLDistanceFilterNone;
    [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        if (error == nil&& [placemarks count] >0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            NSString *latitude, *longitude, *state, *country;
            latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
            longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
            self.theCoord.text = [[latitude stringByAppendingString:@", "] stringByAppendingString:longitude];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    }];
    // Turn off the location manager to save power.
    [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Location updates should work with no internet, but geocoding will not. That is a network service. My guess is that you are getting location updates but the call to reverseGeocodeLocation is failing. You should set breakpoints and trace through your code to see what's happening.

Comment: So is there a method to get Latitude and Longitude coordinates without needing cellular or wifi data?

Comment: The standard location services should work without a network / data connection. Note that if you're testing this by enabling airplane mode that also disables location services. You can test this by inserting a break point before you make your reverse geo code request and looking at the values.

Comment: Your current code using `CLLocationManager` to get the user's location should work even without an internet connection. The call to `reverseGeocodeLocation` will not work unless you have a network connection however.

Comment: As Manish points out in his answer, you need to create a new geocoder object for each lat/long you want to reverse-geocode, and you need to be careful not to geocode too often or Apple's servers will block your geocoding requests.

Comment: Thanks.  Hadn't realized the reverseGeocodeLocation block was where I had the code set the lat/long values.  Moved those in front of it, to prevent it from messing up again.

Answer (score 0):

Apple doc says https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/clgeocoder

`A geocoder object is a single-shot object that works with a network-based service to look up placemark information for its specified coordinate value.`

Comment: Good point, but that's not really an answer to the OPs question